# Error when calling session object inside Method decorated by Spring websocket annotations

Tags: session, grails, spring-websocket

Using the [Grails spring-websocket plugin](https://github.com/zyro23/grails-spring-websocket):

#### CurrentStatusController.groovy

```
@MessageMapping("/personExist")
@SendTo("/topic/personExist")
protected Boolean personExist(String personId) {    
    return (Person.get(personId)!=null)
}
```

Saving all id of persons in `session` list `personIds`, then handle the same method using a session object

#### CurrentStatusController.groovy

```
@MessageMapping("/personExist")
@SendTo("/topic/personExist")
protected Boolean personExist(String personId) {
    return (session.personIds.contains(personId))
}
```

The first works, the last does not work with the following error message :

```
ERROR springwebsocket.GrailsSimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler  -
Unhandled exception Message: No thread-bound request found: Are you
referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or
processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
message, your code is probably running outside of
DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
request.
    Line | Method
->>   53 | getSession in org.grails.plugins.web.rest.api.ControllersRestApi
```

How to make Spring-WebSocket methods accepts session object?

Comment: Spring Session (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session) comes to the rescue for such a case!